# "DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE" bash: syntax error near unexpected token

Tags: python, django, visual-studio-code

I wonder why I get this error :

> django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Passing a 3-tuple to
> include() is not supported. Pass a 2-tuple containing the list of
> patterns and app_name, and provide the namespace argument to include()
> instead. (.venv)

this is my code :

```
$ python manage.py runserver 9999
```

then I tried

```
$ os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "mysite.settings")
```

however it turns out:

> bash: syntax error near unexpected token `"DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE",'
> (.venv)

In manage.py, the code already exits:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
import sys
if __name__ == "__main__":
    os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "PRO2.settings")
    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
```

what can I do next?

Comment: It looks like you're trying to type Python code at the bash prompt (`$`). That's not going to work; bash has its own syntax that has nothing to do with Python.

Comment: In the manage.py, relevant code already exit like this: #!/usr/bin/env python
import os
import sys

if __name__ == "__main__":
    os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "PRO2.settings")

    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line

    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)

Comment: Sure, python can run python code. But you can't run that code at the shell prompt. If you want to set an environment variable in bash, you need to do it using bash syntax. [For example](https://devconnected.com/set-environment-variable-bash-how-to/).